# Is is useful to code this kind of application?

Tags: linux, windows

I got 3 windows pcs at home for which I need to keep the latest versions of (legit) software I download from the internet for Windows platform (VLC, FileZilla, ExpressVPN, VirtualBox, FFMpeg....) whatever. The usual process is to dowload the soft, put it on the NAS and each pc will be able to get it for himself. (No Chocolate setup here, might be the way to go ?)

On the NAS, Apps are dispatched in their own folders (Security, App Development, Video Processing) to find them more easely.

Problem is how to clean up the previous versions in each category because I am lazy to put corect file in correct folder and remove previous versions.

I plan to develop a small Python script (could be Jscript, java, I do not care the language) which does the following :

Go to each category folder and extract all radices : VirtualBox-7.36.exe becomes VirtualBox, VirtualBox-7.37.exe is ignored, store this in a list.
Go to folder "ToSort" which contains all latest versions, unsorted.
Search for each Radix, move it the corresponding folder, Repeat

Then, go to each category and find all matching filenames for each radices and keep the highest version number, remove the rest.

I can develop it, it is no big deal but this takes some time (Regex, Dictionaries, Logging, Testing, Deploying...)

My Question (At last) :
Does it worth the hassle ? or is there a better way ?

Thanks for your input (I do not want the code, just ideas) ;)